Strategies for removing nested IF conditions
I'd like to ask for help. I'm trying to improve some code, but I can't think of anything to solve it. How can I remove these nested IF conditions? Could someone help me? I have many conditions and the code is very messy, but I have no idea how to improve it in this scenario.
for (Skill skill : skills.values())
{
    if (skill.isPassive())
        continue;

    if (aiSkillLists == null)
        aiSkillLists = new EnumMap<>(AISkillScope.class);

    final List<AISkillScope> aiSkillScopes = new ArrayList<>();
    final AISkillScope shortOrLongRangeScope = skill.getCastRange() <= 150 ? AISkillScope.SHORT_RANGE : AISkillScope.LONG_RANGE;
    if (skill.isSuicideAttack())
    {
        aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.SUICIDE);
    }
    else
    {
        aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.GENERAL);

        if (skill.isContinuous())
        {
            if (!skill.isDebuff())
            {
                aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.BUFF);
            }
            else
            {
                aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.DEBUFF);
                aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.COT);
                aiSkillScopes.add(shortOrLongRangeScope);
            }
        }
        else if (skill.hasEffectType(EffectType.DISPEL, EffectType.DISPEL_BY_SLOT))
        {
            aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.NEGATIVE);
            aiSkillScopes.add(shortOrLongRangeScope);
        }
        else if (skill.hasEffectType(EffectType.HEAL))
        {
            aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.HEAL);
        }
        else if (skill.hasEffectType(EffectType.PHYSICAL_ATTACK, EffectType.PHYSICAL_ATTACK_HP_LINK, EffectType.MAGICAL_ATTACK, EffectType.DEATH_LINK, EffectType.HP_DRAIN))
        {
            aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.ATTACK);
            aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.UNIVERSAL);
            aiSkillScopes.add(shortOrLongRangeScope);
        }
        else if (skill.hasEffectType(EffectType.SLEEP))
        {
            aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.IMMOBILIZE);
        }
        else if (skill.hasEffectType(EffectType.STUN, EffectType.ROOT))
        {
            aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.IMMOBILIZE);
            aiSkillScopes.add(shortOrLongRangeScope);
        }
        else if (skill.hasEffectType(EffectType.MUTE, EffectType.FEAR))
        {
            aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.COT);
            aiSkillScopes.add(shortOrLongRangeScope);
        }
        else if (skill.hasEffectType(EffectType.PARALYZE))
        {
            aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.IMMOBILIZE);
            aiSkillScopes.add(shortOrLongRangeScope);
        }
        else if (skill.hasEffectType(EffectType.DMG_OVER_TIME, EffectType.DMG_OVER_TIME_PERCENT))
        {
            aiSkillScopes.add(shortOrLongRangeScope);
        }
        else if (skill.hasEffectType(EffectType.RESURRECTION))
        {
            aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.RES);
        }
        else
        {
            aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.UNIVERSAL);
        }
    }

    for (AISkillScope aiSkillScope : aiSkillScopes)
    {
        List<Skill> aiSkills = aiSkillLists.get(aiSkillScope);
        if (aiSkills == null)
            aiSkills = new ArrayList<>();
            aiSkillLists.put(aiSkillScope, aiSkills);

        aiSkills.add(skill);
    }
}


This really isn't that bad.  I've seen much worse.

As mentioned, this is not so bad YET. I would suggest looking into Strategy design pattern so you can create specific class to handle the scopes (suicide, general) and then have a class to handle the specifics of each. there is no way around the checks though what you could do is to create predicates for each, add them to a map and then a FOR loop on the map to check each

Rather than answer with a solution, I would suggest that you do the Gilded Rose code Kata. You can see some really good videos of other devs tackling the problem, probably my favourite is from Ivan Moore - there's no commentary, but the end result is gorgeous (in OO terms). A functional solution is not that different. Also, depending on what game you are coding, I would suggest to go through the rabbit hole of Data-Oriented Design.

There are two things you can do IMO.

Modularization: Extract some logic containing if clauses to different methods.
eg:-

# existing code...

if (skill.isContinuous()) {
            processContinuousSkill(skill, aiSkillScopes, shortOrLongRangeScope);
}

# existing code...

void processContinuousSkill(Skill skill, List<AISkillScope> aiSkillScopes, AISkillScope shortOrLongRangeScope) {
    if (!skill.isDebuff()) {
        aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.BUFF);
    } else {
        aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.DEBUFF);
        aiSkillScopes.add(AISkillScope.COT);
        aiSkillScopes.add(shortOrLongRangeScope);
    }
}


Using computeIfAbsent to handle the logic in the nested for loop.

for (AISkillScope aiSkillScope : aiSkillScopes) {
        aiSkillLists.computeIfAbsent(aiSkillScope, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(skill);
}

References
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-


I have many conditions and the code is very messy, but I have no idea how to improve it in this scenario.

Without seeing the EffectType and AISkillScope types, it's hard to fully comment but I would think that adding something like getScopes() onto the EffectType might improve your code.  So then you would do something like:
for (effectType : skill.getEffectTypes()) {
    aiSkillScopes.addAll(effectType.getScopes());
}

Maybe instead you would have an addScopes(Collection) method and you would pass in the aiSkillScopes to the method which would add the scopes associated with the effect.
Not 100% sure what to do with shortOrLongRangeScope but I could see each effect having a boolean method something like hasShortOrLongRangeScope() so after the for loop you would do something like:
if (effectType.hasShortOrLongRangeScope()) {
    aiSkillScopes.add(shortOrLongRangeScope);
}

You could also pass in the shortOrLongRangeScope to the addScopes() method so that the effectType could add it or not to the scopes collection.
Hope this helps.
